# Hbase schema design for new table for realtime time series

Tags: hadoop, nosql, hbase

I have some domains data e.g., pages etc., in hbase table. I have to show its statistics in real time e.g., number of documents, invalid/valid documents etc. for weekly basis. 
For this purpose, I am thinking to create another Hbase table for these statistics. An MR job will update this new table for new week statistics after processing original table. Now what should be the schema of my new table. Is this right approach ?
I have to visualize top 100 domains real-time (some sorting needed).

```
Data format like
domain, week1-docs, week2-docs,week3-docs ...
```

Further, It is also expected that data will grow with  time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you want to fetch the data from HBase you have a few possibilities. In fact, since HBase provides automatic lexicographic ordering of the row keys, you can improve your `Get` or `Scan` operations as follows:

1) You are going to be interested in all the domains of a given week

```
[rowKey] -> [colName0] = [colValue0], ...
"2019-01" -> domain0 = "{data for domain0}", domain1 = "{data for domain1}"
...
"2019-52" -> ...
```

In this case you can either use a `Get` operation to obtain all the domains' data for a given week or a `Scan` operation to get all the domains' data across multiple weeks.

2) You are going to be interested in a single domain at a time, across multiple weeks

```
[rowKey] -> [colName0] = [colValue0], ...
"domain0_2019-01" -> data = "{data for domain0 on week 1}"
...
"domain0_2019-52" -> data = "{data for domain0 on week 52}"
"domain1_2019-01" -> data = "{data for domain1 on week 1}"
...
```

In this case you could get the data of a single domain for a single week by building a `Get` accordingly, or you could get the data for all (or a subset) of the weeks for a given domain by using a `Scan` with a partial `START_ROW` and `END_ROW`. For instance a `Scan` with a `START_ROW = "domain0_2019"` and a `STOP_ROW = "domain0_2020"` will give you the data for the whole 2019 for domain0.

3) You are going to be interested in a single week and single domain at a time

```
[rowKey] -> [colName0] = [colValue0], ...
"2019-01_domain0" -> data = "{data for domain0 on week 1}"
"2019-01_domain1" -> data = "{data for domain1 on week 1}"
...
"2019-52_domain0" -> data = "{data for domain0 on week 52}"
"2019-52_domain1" -> data = "{data for domain1 on week 52}"
...
```

This approach is similar to the first one and differs from it based on how much data are you going to store in the actual column. This approach prefers the usage of `Get` operations to get data about a specific week for a specific domain.

Other considerations can be done and it really depends on how you want to extract the data from the HBase table, if you will use only `Get` operations or you will also need to `Scan` data, etc...

Answer (score 1):

```
domain, week1-docs, week2-docs,week3-docs ...
```

You can use this approach to store data, as you can store basically unlimited columns in HBase, but I prefer the following:

```
domain_week_id [row_key], week-docs
```

as an example

```
domainName_2019_24, {docs data}
```

This way you can fetch a particular week much more efficient and it will scale better.

You can also specify a range for the row key with the desired week interval and it will fetch all docs from those weeks.